# How to avoid providing absolute path of git repo while cloning?

Tags: git, git-clone

I am trying to host a git repository. I am now able to clone git repo on any machine within the network with:

```
git clone gituser@192.168.0.133:/home/gituser/repositories/gitosis-admin.git
```

But I need to give absolute path of the repo location.

Is it possible to clone without specifying repo path? like for e.g.

```
git clone gituser@192.168.0.133:gitosis-admin.git
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to clone using a path relative to your home directory on the remote machine. So, for example, `git clone gituser@192.168.0.133:/home/gituser/repositories/gitosis-admin.git` could become `git clone gituser@192.168.0.133:repositories/gitosis-admin.git`.

Comment: I found a workaround like I created a softlink in / to ~/repositoris/gitosis-admin.git and now it works with git clone gituser@192.168.0.133:/gitosis-admin.git command. 

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend doing a softlink in ~ to ~/repositories/gitosis-admin.git, so that you can do `git clone gituser@192.168.0.133:gitosis-admin.git`. The problem with linking in / is that it pollutes the root on a system that may have multiple users (and that's why you have a home directory in the first place).

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your suggestion.